# From Login screen to `UITabBarController`

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have a Login screen which checks if the inserted Password is correct.

After that I want to switch from the Login screen to a `UITabBarController`.

Code from LoginViewController.m:

```
-(IBAction)LoginButton:(id)sender {

    [PassWortEingabe resignFirstResponder];
    NSString *pnssPasswortEingabe = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",PassWortEingabe.text];
    NSString *pnssPasswortString  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s","Hallo"];

    if( [pnssPasswortEingabe isEqualToString: pnssPasswortString ]){

        DebugTextView.text = @"Login succesfull";
        //PassWortEingabe = 0;
        //[PassWortEingabe resignFirstResponder];
    }else{

        DebugTextView.text = @"Login unsuccesfull";
        //PassWortEingabe = 0;
       //[PassWortEingabe resignFirstResponder];
    }


}
```

I want jump to the `UITabBarController` when the Login is sucessful ...

Answer (score 0):

```
if( [pnssPasswortEingabe isEqualToString: pnssPasswortString ]){

    DebugTextView.text = @"Login succesfull";
    MyTabBarClass *myTabBar = [[MyTabBarClass alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    myTabBar.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:myTabBar animated:YES];
    //PassWortEingabe = 0;
    //[PassWortEingabe resignFirstResponder];
}else{

    DebugTextView.text = @"Login unsuccesfull";
    //PassWortEingabe = 0;
    //[PassWortEingabe resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as the code below.

```
if( [pnssPasswortEingabe isEqualToString: pnssPasswortString ]){
   // This is for iOS 5.0 and above.
    UITabBarController *myTabBarController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myTabBarController"];
    [myTabBarController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentViewController:myTabBarController animated:YES completion:^(void){
        // You can set some sort of completion block here which will run when all other code finishes, this can just be nil.
     }];
} else {
    DebugTextView.text = @"Login unsuccesfull";
}
```

You can also replace this line with

```
[self presentViewController:myTabBarController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

replace with

```
[self presentModalViewController:myTabBarController animated:YES];
```

but this has been deprecated in iOS 6.0. So if you are making your app for iOS 5.0 and above you are best of using the first line so you don't have to make changes in the future.

The above code is made to use storyboards if you want to do it with nib files then change

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myTabBarController"];
```

to

```
[[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myTabBarController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why not to use the segue in the storyboard directly?

Comment: @Odelya No reason not too at all. I just prefer to do it in code that's all.